# Is there a better way to chain async tasks other than using ContinueWith method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am chaining my async tasks like this,

```
await MyTask_1().ContinueWith(async x=>
{
    // do other stuff
    await MyTask_2().ContinueWith(async y => 
    {
        await MyTask_3().ContinueWith(async z => 
        {
            // and more tasks
        });
    }); 
});
```

I want to run one task when the previous task is completed so I found only that way to chain them.

But is there any other less ugly or cleaner or shorter way to achieve this?

Comment: You might be missing the obvious here, just write them one after another.  `await MyTask_1(); await MyTask_2(); await MyTask_3();` The `await` operator does all the magic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`await` already pauses the current code flow (and releases the thread) and waits for the asynchronous task, so it won't execute the next line of code until that happens. You should be able to simply write

```
await MyTask_1();
await MyTask_2();
await MyTask_3();
```

That's why it's called `await`!

Comment: Great! Thanks! So if I write something like this `await MyTask_1(); int i =1; NonAsyncMethod(); await MyTask_2();` will it still wait for first task to complete then will run non sync methods and then will call mytask 2 async task, am I right?

Comment: Yes. Just try it and see for yourself, it's trivial to test that.

Comment: Nitpick: It doesn't "pause the thread", that thread is released to go do other stuff.  It pauses the current code-path.